# django choose template from admin panel without restarting server

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to create a website with multiple template for all pages.

I've created a **templates** folder and there are 3 folders in it. each folder contains *base.html*, *home.html*, *etc*.

Admin can choose each template from admin panel and in my view load template like this.

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    default_template = CustomTemplate.objects.first().name
    template_name = default_template + '/home.html'
```

The problem is **I have to restart server to apply admin's changes**.
Is there any way to do this without restarting server?
I've also tried to enable / disable loader cache but I guess the problem is not depends to cache system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything defined directly at class level will persist for the entirety of a process.

Luckily, Django's class-based views provide a series of hooks so that you can define things on a per-request basis. In this case, the method you want is [`get_template_names`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names) (which returns a list of templates to search for).

So:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        default_template = CustomTemplate.objects.first().name
        return ['{}/home.html'.format(default_template)]
```